# resilience4j-spring-boot-2 annotations (@Retry, @CircuitBreaker...) are completely ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

*I spent a whole day trying to find why this does not work so I think it might be useful if I share the question and the answer.*

The [Resilience4j library](https://resilience4j.readme.io/) provides an elegant annotation-based solution from Spring Boot 2. All you need to do is just annotate a method (or a class) with one of the provided annotations, such as `@CircuitBreaker`, `@Retry`, `@RateLimiter`, `@Bulkhead`, `@Thread` and the appropriate resilience pattern is automagically added.

I added the expected dependency to the Maven pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the compiler is happy, so I can add the annotations:

```java
...
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import io.github.resilience4j.retry.annotation.Retry;
...

@Service
public class MyService {
    ...
    @Retry(name = "get-response")
    public MyResponse getResponse(MyRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The program compiles, runs, however **the annotations are completely ignored**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [resilience4j-spring-boot2 documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3):

> The module expects that `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `spring-boot-starter-aop` are already provided at runtime.

So the whole trick is to add *also* the missing dependencies to the Maven `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```