@CircuitBreaker fallback method doesn't work with @Valid @RequestBody exception
I have create a small spring api proyect and I would like do an exception handler with CircuitBreaker for valid JSON exceptions.
This is my object model:
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Client {
    
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private Integer age;
}

My controller post method is:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {
@PostMapping("/create")

    @CircuitBreaker(name="validationDataHandler", fallbackMethod = "fallbackCreateClient")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Client>> createClient(@Valid @RequestBody Client client) {
        System.out.println("------- METHOD CREATE -------");
        return clientService.createClient(client)
                        .map(created -> ResponseEntity.ok(created));
    }

private Mono<ResponseEntity<Client>> fallbackCreateClient(Client client, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("<<<< CIRCUIT BREAKER >>>>");
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest()));
    }

}

clientService has connect with the database, and I'm using spring mongodb reactive to manage the connections with the database.
when the body request has empty field an exception is throw, but circuitbreaker has never fired.
I think because the exception is thron before the method start but I'm not sure how can I use circuitbreaker for cases like this.
I hope someone can helpme solving this problem
EDIT 1*
the dependencies used are:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.amigo.programador</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ms-client</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amigo.programador</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



Since you are importing javax.validation, I suppose you are not using the latest spring boot artifacts. Can you please post the relevant pom dependencies and the version numbers, and which CircuitBreaker implementation you are using (i.e. Resilience4j or others)?

Do you have the required dependencies, namely resilience4j-reactor and resilience4j-spring-boot2? You can also miss other dependensies, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/64269326/2886891 - this older post is not reactor-related, but in my experience the Resilience library is quite silent in case of missing dependencies, it just doesn't work without any warning :)

Im using spring-boot-starter-validation and spring 2.7.5, and circuit breaker spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j

I think because the exception is thron before the method start but I'm not sure how can I use circuitbreaker for cases like this.
Yes I also think this is the case here.
You could move the @Valid into clientService.createClient?

According to the documentation, it seems like you should use the org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j dependency.
I suspect that your annotation brings the circuit breaker functionality to the Mono itself, so to its "construction time", and not to its "execution time".
Try the spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j dependency. And check carefully for any missing dependencies. My former experience with the resilience library is that it doesn't tell you when it is missing something, it just very silently doesn't work :)
Btw, when you want to log the reactive calls properly, you should not use System.out.println() in the method before the Mono, but inside the Mono "stream":
Mono.just(...)
    .doOnNext(item -> /* here is your log */)
    .map(...)

Then your log is written in the "execution time" of the Mono.
Of course the logging on the method level also sometimes makes sense, you should just be aware of the difference.
